# Tuist/XCode invalid redeclaration of Sentry

Tags: swift, sentry, swift-package-manager, tuist

So I'm trying to set up a multi-module application with Tuist, and I'm unable to build it.

I get a series of these errors with different

> [REDACTED]/Tuist/Dependencies/SwiftPackageManager/.build/checkouts/sentry-cocoa/Sources/Sentry/Public/SentryDefines.h:104:28 Redefinition of 'SentryLogLevel'

I've tried various build settings, as well as clean fetches and the like.

It looks like some people are having similar problems in [this Issue](https://github.com/tuist/tuist/issues/4688).

As you can see I've tried the recommended settings, to no avail.

Here's Dependencies.swift:

```
var swiftPackageManagerDependencies = SwiftPackageManagerDependencies([
        .remote(
            url: "https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa.git",
            requirement: .upToNextMajor(from: "8.19.0")
        ),
        .remote(
            url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git",
            requirement: .upToNextMajor(from: "5.8.1")
        ),
        .remote(
            url: "https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.swift",
            requirement: .upToNextMajor(from: "2.5.0")
        ),
        .remote(
            url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",
            requirement: .upToNextMajor(from: "10.20.0")
        )
    ]
)

let dependencies = Dependencies(
    swiftPackageManager: swiftPackageManagerDependencies,
    platforms: [.iOS]
)
```

`Project.swift`

```
import ProjectDescription
import ProjectDescriptionHelpers

let projectSettings: Settings = .settings(
    base: [
        "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER": "NO",
        "CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES": "YES",
        "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS": "-Xcc -Wno-error=non-modular-include-in-framework-module"
        ]
)

let targetSettings: Settings = .settings(
    base: [
        "USE_HEADERMAP": "YES",
        "OTHER_LDFLAGS": "-ObjC",
        "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS": ["$(inherited)",
                                "Tuist/Dependencies/SwiftPackageManager/.build/checkouts/sentry-cocoa/Sources/Sentry/**"]
    ]
)

let project = Project(
    name: "CoreData",
//    settings: projectSettings,
    targets: [
        Target(
            name: "CoreData",
            destinations: .iOS,
            product: .framework,
            bundleId: "domain.coredata",
            sources: ["Sources/**"],
            resources: ["Resources/**"],
            dependencies: [
                .external(name: "Alamofire", condition: nil),
                .external(name: "Auth0", condition: nil),
                .external(name: "FirebaseMessaging", condition: nil),
                .external(name: "Sentry", condition: nil)
            ],
            settings: targetSettings
        ),
        Target(
            name: "CoreDatatests",
            destinations: .iOS,
            product: .unitTests,
            bundleId: "domain.coredata.tests",
            sources: ["Tests/**"],
            resources: ["Resources/**"],
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "CoreData", condition: .none)
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```